# Hyper-V External Switch and Windows Shares

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, network-share, windows-10

I'm trying to make a Windows share available to an Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V while also allowing that VM to access the web for ongoing dev work (this is a local ansible host machine, which I don't think is too important).

However, whenever I create a Virtual External Switch it appears to create a bridge that blocks my attempts at sharing the folder (C:\Share) altogether, including with other people connected to the LAN in my office.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the virtual machine settings or the switches that would make this fixable?

Edit: Additionally if I try using only an internal switch, I receive an error 'Network is unreachable' when trying to mount the share.

The External Switch:
[image: External Switch configuration]

The VM (note that I'm just testing with the internal switch):
[image]

Comment: `Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the virtual machine settings or the switches that would make this fixable?` - How would we know if you're misunderstanding something? You haven't told us what your understanding is. How about sharing some details and images of your Hyper-V configuration, guest configuration, ip settings for the host and guest, error messages, etc.?

Comment: Hi @joeqwerty I'll attach the images, but they don't really help as the issue is that as soon as I create an external virtual switch my shares stop working over LAN. If I delete the virtual switch, they start working again over the LAN. I cannot access the host from the VM if I put it on an internal switch. There's no error messages, just complete failure of share functionality as soon as an external switch is added, and no access to the network when using an internal one.

Comment: Are the ip address settings of the guest appropriate for communication with the host?

Comment: @joeqwerty The guest has a different IP from the host, but I feel the need to reiterate, I'm not even to the point where I'm testing host<->guest communication, the share can no longer be accessed on the LAN (by other physical machines) immediately when I add a virtual external switch even though I can ping the host from the guest.

Comment: OK. Gotcha. It is probably due to the fact that Hyper-V creates a bridge when creating a Virtual Switch with a wireless adapter. Try unchecking the option to allow the management operating system to share this adapter, assuming you have another NIC that you can use for accessing the host. If not, you might try this instead: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network

Comment: @joeqwerty You're a lifesaver, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking to do. I'll try to figure it out, if you want to post this as an answer I'll edit it a bit to add in my experience but you can get the points.